# My Vuex form get the first field but not the second, failing silently

Tags: javascript, forms, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I'm just beginning with Vuex and I have an input form that store just one input field and not the second.

I cant just figure out what's wrong. 
The form is in the following component page

```
$ cat src/components/AddBar.vue 
<template>
  <div class="action-bar">
    <input
      placeholder="bar name..."
      class="bar-input"
      type="text"
      :value="barNameToCreate"
      @input="setBarNameToCreate($event.target.value)"
      @keypress.enter="triggerAddBarAction"
    />
    <input
      placeholder="address..."
      class="bar-input"
      type="text"
      :value="barAddressToCreate"
      @input="setBarAddressToCreate($event.target.value)"
      @keypress.enter="triggerAddBarAction"
    />
    <div
      :class="{ disabled: barCreationPending }"
      class="create-bar-btn"
      @click="triggerAddBarAction"
    >
      add bar
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapMutations, mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: mapState('bars', [
    'barNameToCreate',
    'barAddressToCreate',
    'barCreationPending'
  ]),
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations('bars', ['setBarNameToCreate', 'setBarAddressToCreate']),
    ...mapActions('bars', ['triggerAddBarAction'])
  }
}
</script>
```

When I submit the form I get the first field but not the second and not any error in the console:

[image]

What am I missing?

Here there are some relevant file store structure:

```
$ ls -l src/store/bars/
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 lsoave lsoave 1400 Jun 24 18:59 bars.actions.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 lsoave lsoave  297 Jun 24 18:59 bars.getters.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 lsoave lsoave  890 Jun 26 21:37 bars.mutations.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 lsoave lsoave  136 Jun 26 21:33 bars.state.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 lsoave lsoave  231 Jun 24 18:59 index.js
```

and the some relative mapMutations, mapState, mapActions contents:

```
$ cat src/store/bars/index.js
import state from './bars.state'
import mutations from './bars.mutations'
import actions from './bars.actions'
import getters from './bars.getters'

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters
}

$ cat src/store/bars/bars.mutations.js
export default {
  /* Bar input name */
  setBarNameToCreate: (state, barNameToCreate) =>
    (state.barNameToCreate = barNameToCreate),

  /* Bar input address*/
  setBarAddressToCreate: (state, barAddressToCreate) =>
    (state.barAddressToCreate = barAddressToCreate),

  /* Bars */
  setBars: (state, bars) => (state.bars = bars),
  addBar: (state, bar) => state.bars.push(bar),
  removeBarById: (state, barId) => {
    const index = state.bars.findIndex(bar => bar.id === barId)
    state.bars.splice(index, 1)
  },

  /* Bars deletion */
  addBarDeletionPending: (state, barId) => state.barDeletionPending.push(barId),
  removeBarDeletionPending: (state, barId) => {
    const index = state.bars.findIndex(bar => bar.id === barId)
    state.barDeletionPending.splice(index, 1)
  },

  /* Bar creation */
  setBarCreationPending: (state, value) => (state.barCreationPending = value)
}

$ cat  src/store/bars/bars.state.js
export default {
  bars: null,
  barNameToCreate: '',
  barAddressToCreate: '',
  barDeletionPending: [],
  barCreationPending: false
}

$ cat  src/store/bars/bars.actions.js
import UserBarsDB from '@/firebase/user-bars-db'

export default {
  /**
   * Fetch bars of current loggedin user
   */
  getUserBars: async ({ rootState, commit }) => {
    const userBarDb = new UserBarsDB(rootState.authentication.user.id)

    const bars = await userBarDb.readAll()
    commit('setBars', bars)
  },

  /**
   * Create a bar for current loggedin user
   */
  createUserBar: async ({ commit, rootState }, bar) => {
    const userBarDb = new UserBarsDB(rootState.authentication.user.id)

    commit('setBarCreationPending', true)
    const createdBar = await userBarDb.create(bar)
    commit('addBar', createdBar)
    commit('setBarCreationPending', false)
  },

  /**
   * Create a new bar for current loggedin user and reset bar name input
   */
  triggerAddBarAction: ({ dispatch, state, commit }) => {
    if (state.barNameToCreate === '') return

    const bar = { name: state.barNameToCreate }
    commit('setBarNameToCreate', '')
    dispatch('createUserBar', bar)
  },

  /**
   * Delete a user bar from its id
   */
  deleteUserBar: async ({ rootState, commit, getters }, barId) => {
    if (getters.isBarDeletionPending(barId)) return

    const userBarsDb = new UserBarsDB(rootState.authentication.user.id)

    commit('addBarDeletionPending', barId)
    await userBarsDb.delete(barId)
    commit('removeBarById', barId)
    commit('removeBarDeletionPending', barId)
  }
}
```

Comment: I think we'll need to see the relevant sections of the store code.

Comment: @skirtle    ok, just edited

Comment: `triggerAddBarAction` adds `barNameToCreate` to `bar` but it doesn't do anything with `barAddressToCreate`.

Comment: @skirtle   my G.. you got it!  I completely miss it.  Now is fixed,  if you like to post the answer I'm gonna flag that one ... Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in `triggerAddBarAction`:

```js
  triggerAddBarAction: ({ dispatch, state, commit }) => {
    if (state.barNameToCreate === '') return

    const bar = { name: state.barNameToCreate }
    commit('setBarNameToCreate', '')
    dispatch('createUserBar', bar)
  },
```

It adds `barNameToCreate` to `bar` but it doesn't do anything with `barAddressToCreate`. `bar` is then passed to `createUserBar` to make the server call.